# Encrypt APK without obfuscation Dexguard

Tags: java, android, encryption, dexguard

For an evaluation I want to encrypt all strings in my APK file with DexGuard, but without using the obfuscation, shrinking or optimization options.
**Is this possible or am I forced to obfuscate the APK to encrypt it?**
I use the following command line to encrypt all classes:

```
java -jar dexguard.jar @conf.pro -dontwarn -dontobfuscate -dontshrink -dontoptimize -injar in.jar -libraryjars android.jar -outjars out.apk
```

The conf.pro looks like this:

```
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
#...
-encryptstrings class uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.BuildConfig
-encryptstrings class uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher$ViewDelegate
-encryptstrings class uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher$Options
#...
```

I have used the tool `jar tf ...` to get all class names and then added all classes with `-encryptstrings class ...` after filtering like in the conf.pro file.
My problem is that nothing is encrypted in the out.apk.
**What is wrong with my settings?**
Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried all kind of combinations to encrypt the APK without obfuscation, but it is not possible. **So my resume is that encryption is only possible with obfuscation with DexGuard.**
The only changes I see to encrypt with DexGuard without obfuscation is to encrypt with obfuscation and use the mapping file to restore the names.
But I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, for string encryption to work, you need to enable obfuscation.

In order to prevent any obfuscation of classes/methods/fields you can add the following configuration:

```
-keep class * { *; }
```